# Browsing a Couchbase DB

Tags: couchbase

Coming from SQL Server I'm used to using the SQL Management Studio to look at the data in the DB.

Is there any way (GUI/Web Tool or Console app) that would allow me to simply view documents in the Couchbase DB?

Comment: Couchbase has embeded web interface, that is running "out of the box" and you can access it on 8091 port.

Answer (score 4):

You can view the data for pasting the following into a browser, if running locally then you can just put localhost in below, otherwise put the ip of the server down (make sure you have the correct ports open).

```
http://IP_ADDRESS_HERE:8091
```

Visit for which ports couchbase needs open http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#network-ports

You can browse the data or pull back a specific document if you know its key, go to Data Buckets and then click documents on the bucket you want to view for a list of the documents.

Visit for a more detailed overview http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.2/#administration-tasks

Comment: but is there a way I can easily filter the data? is there a software like MongoHub where I can search values within my documents quickly?